# how to fix the map drifting in rviz?

Tags: slam, navigation, hector, hector-localization, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've run the hokuyo laser and microstrain imu with my regular PC and try to map out but the drifting come along when turning, or object close to the laser which make the map miserable.....

Here is the trail .bagfile of hector slam

http://code.google.com/p/hectormapping/downloads/list

Is there anyone know that how to fix the problem?

(Thanks for your helping )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38224/how-to-fix-the-map-drifting-in-rviz-?/) by [jas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2638/jas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The combination of a relatively low update rate (10 Hz) and range (4m) Hokuyo URG-04LX LIDAR and an environment that at times does not provide many features in a scan makes your scenario a difficult one. You could try if a laser_scan_matcher/gmapping combination fares better for this one.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2638/jas/) on 2012-07-09**:
Is it possible to use the combination of a laser_scan_matcher and gmapping for UAV flight SLAM? (for a better mapping) Because I would like to implement it on UAV...the above bag file is the handhold mapping though (thanks for helping)

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-07-10**:
Yes it is possible, however this approach also does not work all the time. A example with a comparison between both approaches for a quadrotor application can be seen here: http://answers.ros.org/question/35684/icp-scan-matching-failure/

**Comment by [elva](https://answers.ros.org/users/4431/elva/) on 2013-03-27**:
Hi, have you sovled the problem? because i have the same problem as you, i have a hokuyo UGR-04lX and a microstrain imu,however when i use hokuyo doing hector-mapping,ht map overlaps and very messy,any help?